# How to standardize variables of different datasets in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list of dataframes

```
mydata1<-data.frame(Age=c(25,30),Sexe=c("F","M"),Weight=c(65,90))

mydata2<-data.frame(Age=c(28,27),Sexe=c("F","F"),Weight=c(72,70),Height=c(170,175))

mydata3<-data.frame(Age=c(34,22),Sexe=c("M","F"),Weight=c(58,62),Area=c("A","B"))

mydata4<-data.frame(Age=c(22,27),Sexe=c("F","M"),Weight=c(49,78),
                    Height=c(180,165),Area=c("C","A"),Hobby=c("Movie","Party"))

mydatals<-list(mydata1=mydata1,mydata2=mydata2,mydata3=mydata3,mydata4=mydata4)
```

The goal is to make standardize my dataframes

The variables I am interested in are:

```
myvar_to_select<-c("Age","Sexe","Weight","Height","Area")
```

If the dataframe has not the variable of interest, it should be created and filled with `NA`
Conversly, if it contains an additionnal variable, it must be deleted.

I must have a list of dataframes like below:

```
$mydata1
  Age Sexe Weight Height Area
1  25    F     65     NA   NA
2  30    M     90     NA   NA

$mydata2
  Age Sexe Weight Height Area
1  28    F     72    170   NA
2  27    F     70    175   NA

$mydata3
  Age Sexe Weight Height Area
1  34    M     58     NA    A
2  22    F     62     NA    B

$mydata4
  Age Sexe Weight Height Area
1  22    F     49    180    C
2  27    M     78    165    A
```

Comment: Do you have a typo on `mydata4$Weignt`, should it be `Weight`?

Comment: Sorry @benson23 it is weight instead of weignt. I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lapply(
  mydatals, 
  \(DF) {
    lacking     <- setdiff(myvar_to_select, names(DF))
    DF[lacking] <- NA
    DF[myvar_to_select]
  }
)

# $mydata1
#   Age Sexe Weight Height Area
# 1  25    F     65     NA   NA
# 2  30    M     90     NA   NA
# 
# $mydata2
#   Age Sexe Weight Height Area
# 1  28    F     72    170   NA
# 2  27    F     70    175   NA
# 
# $mydata3
#   Age Sexe Weight Height Area
# 1  34    M     58     NA    A
# 2  22    F     62     NA    B
# 
# $mydata4
#   Age Sexe Weight Height Area
# 1  22    F     49    180    C
# 2  27    M     78    165    A
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? Just to note that "Weight" is misspelled in mydata4.

```r
library(tidyverse)
template <- tibble(Age = NA_real_,
                   Sexe = NA_character_,
                   Weight = NA_real_,
                   Height = NA_real_,
                   Area = NA_character_)

map(mydatals, ~.x %>%
      left_join(template) %>%
      select(all_of(myvar_to_select)))
```